# how to find jsonpath sibling

Tags: jsonpath, karate

I need some help on finding the siblings using jsonpath. I would like to find all locations that has price as $0. Tried few options like $..price[?(@.lowest <= 0)] but it selects only the nodes that matches.

Thanks for your assistance

```
[{
"fromDate": "2018-03-30",
"images": [{
    "type": "LARGE",
    "url": ""
}],
"price": {
    "currencySymbol": "$",
    "lowest": 0
},
"toDate": "2018-04-07",
"location": "Newyork, NY",
"priceSuffix": "per night",
"details": "2-Bedrooms" 
},
{
"fromDate": "2018-03-30",
"images": [{
    "type": "LARGE",
    "url": ""
}],
"price": {
    "currencySymbol": "$",
    "lowest": 0
},
"toDate": "2018-04-07",
"location": "Atlanta, GA",
"priceSuffix": "per night",
"details": "2-Bedrooms" 
}]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a working example based on your data that you can cut and paste and try for your self:

```
* def json = 
"""
[{
"fromDate": "2018-03-30",
"images": [{
    "type": "LARGE",
    "url": ""
}],
"price": {
    "currencySymbol": "$",
    "lowest": 0
},
"toDate": "2018-04-07",
"location": "Newyork, NY",
"priceSuffix": "per night",
"details": "2-Bedrooms" 
},
{
"fromDate": "2018-03-30",
"images": [{
    "type": "LARGE",
    "url": ""
}],
"price": {
    "currencySymbol": "$",
    "lowest": 1
},
"toDate": "2018-04-07",
"location": "Atlanta, GA",
"priceSuffix": "per night",
"details": "2-Bedrooms" 
}]
"""
* def zero = $json[?(@.price.lowest==0)]
* match zero[0].location == 'Newyork, NY'
* def one = $json[?(@.price.lowest==1)]
* match one[0].location == 'Atlanta, GA'
```